# How to add prefix to object keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have object:

```
{
  cart: 4,
  trolley: 10,
  car: 2,
}
```

How can I turn it into:

```
{
  shopping_cart: 4,
  shopping_trolley: 10,
  shopping_car: 2,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the keys of the object in an array using the `Object.keys()` method. You can then use the `Array.reduce()` method to iterate over each of the keys and create a new object with desired prefix.

```js
let obj = {
  cart: 4,
  trolley: 10,
  car: 2,
};

let pre = `shopping_`;

let nObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, c) => (a[`${pre}${c}`] = obj[c], a), {});

console.log(nObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried so far?

```js
var obj = {
  cart: 4,
  trolley: 10,
  car: 2
}

for (var key in obj) {
  obj["shopping_" + key] = obj[key]
  delete obj[key]
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const createPrefixObjectKeys => prefix => source => {
  const prefixedSourceTuples = Object.entries(source).map(
    ([key, value]) => [
      `${prefix}${key}`,
       value
     ]
  );

  return Object.fromEntries(prefixedSourceTuples);
}

// use
const prefixObjectShopping = createPrefixObjectKeys('shopping_');

// where x is your object
const prefixed = prefixObjectShopping(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add keys even to **nested** objects in object. Use this (propably the easiest method)

```
function addKeyPrefixes(object, prefix){
    return JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(object).replace(/(?<=[{,]{1}\s*")(.+?)(?="\s*:)/gim, `${prefix}$1`)
    )
}

let obj = {
  'a' : {
    'b': 'c'
  },
  'd': 4
}

console.log(addKeyPrefixes(obj, '_'))

// {
//   '_a': {
//     '_b': 'c'
//   },
//   '_d': 4
// }
```